# ASP.NET 4.0 C# "state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted." MasterPage->Aspx->Ascx

Tags: c#, ajax, state

This is my first SO post, so please forgive any faux pas. I feel as though I've tried everything on every post related to this error (disable viewstate, noCache, etc) and I'm at my wits end.

I have a blank project with a single master page, a single page, and a single control.

The page (aspx) loads using the master page. This works fine. There is a button on the page which loads the control (the ascx) onto the aspx in the section called divRightMainView. This also works fine (which is where my problem seems to differ from all others I've found...). There is a button on the ascx which is supposed to call the code-behind of the ascx - this is where I get the "state information" error.

This is the aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"                   EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Outer.aspx.cs"   Inherits="TestProject.Outer" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        function loadUserView(viewToLoad) {
            PageMethods.RenderControl(viewToLoad, onSuccess, onError);
        }

        function onSuccess(results) {
            alert(results);
            var command = results.split('##')[0];

            if (command == 'loadView') {
                var htmlToLoad = results.split('##')[1];
                $get('divRightMainContentView').innerHTML = htmlToLoad;
            }
        }

        function onError(error) {
            alert('error ' + error);
        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptMgr" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
     <div id="leftSideContent">
         <input type='button' id="clickToLoadASCX" value="Click Me" onclick="loadUserView('/inner.ascx');"/>
         This is the "Outer.aspx" page which will hold the ascx after the button is clicked
     </div>
     <div id="divRightMainContentView">

     </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Aspx code behind (which renders the ascx)

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string RenderControl(String controlName)
    {

        Page page = new Page();
        Control control = page.LoadControl(controlName);
        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        form.Controls.Add(control);
        page.Controls.Add(form);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
        return "loadView##" + writer.ToString();
    }
```

This is the ascx called inner.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="inner.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestProject.inner" %>

<div>
    This is the inner text. When I click the button below I should proceed to inner.ascx.cs to the "PageBehindCall_Submit".
    <asp:Button ID="innerButton" runat="server" onclick="PageBehindCall_Submit" Text="Submit"/> 
</div>
```

And finally, the ascx code-behind

```
protected void PageBehindCall_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "This call does not work!";
}
```

I'm hoping to be able to use the "PageBehindCall_Submit" to process data, grab inputs from the ascx, etc. Let me know if there is a way to make this happen, or another possible work-around? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not load the ascx on page load of the ascx but turn the visibility off rather than manually rendering user control html. This is very weird that it does not hook up with the event in ascx as the control belongs to ascx. But I think you should add it in aspx then try to turn on visibility whenever you need it.

Comment: I ended up taking this advice and using it as my solution. On page load of the aspx I end up registering my ascx controls and then I decide which control should remain visible and hide the others.

My (future) concern for this approach @qamar would be performance. If I were to load 6-10 controls and hide the "inactive" controls I feel as though I could have speed issues on pageLoad. Thoughts?

Comment: What makes you think it will have performance problem? You are loading them once, and just toggling the visibility. Its as good as any other approaches in my opinion.

Comment: If this is done in pageLoad, and they are all registered/loaded with each visit to that page, wouldn't this cause a potential bottleneck on the first load? Your suggestion is working great for me currently, I'm just trying to watch out for future trouble.
Thanks again for all of your help.